# Where to put Aggregation and Composition symbols?

Tags: database, database-design, uml, class-diagram, use-case

I know about Aggregation and Composition though but i am still confused when i start to implement it on the UML class diagram please can some one tell me where i need to put the symbols of Composition and Aggregation and why.

[image: This is the image]

Comment: Why? Because it's written in the UML specs.

Comment: E.g. http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html shows `Library` being composed of `Catalog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put aggregation and composition symbols on the end of the association that is adjacent to the thing that aggregates or composes.

BTW, you appear to have typed the multiplicities into your UML tool where you should have typed the names of the association ends. There is another place to type the multiplicities for those association ends.

Comment: yes i know but where do i have to put those symbols in above example

Comment: You are not asking "where", in general, you want to know "when" to use them as an analyst or a designer?